# Installing Twisted for Python 3.6.1 on Windows got error missing file in Windows SDK

Tags: python, windows, pip, twisted

I tried to install Twisted using pip

```
pip3 install Twisted
```

However I got the following errors

```
    running build_ext
building 'twisted.test.raiser' extension
error: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Windows\\v8.1\\lib'

----------------------------------------
Command "c:\python361\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:
\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-32gww8wb\\twisted\\setup.py';f=ge
tattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.cl
ose();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\User\AppD
ata\Local\Temp\pip-f8823kmo-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externall
y-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Tem
p\pip-build-32gww8wb\twisted\
```

I checked the directory in my computer, I indeed do not have the `lib` folder in path `C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Windows\\v8.1`. I have downloaded Visual Studio 2015 Community but it does not solve the problem.
Is there any thing I need to set after downloading Visual Studio ?
How to solve this problem ?

Updated:
I want to compile this program https://github.com/KDE/kajongg which require me to install Twisted.

Comment: have you installed vcredist (required versions) and SDK for your windows OS?

Comment: @Gahan yes. I have various versions installed. When I was installing Twisted, it was looking for lib folder in version 8.1. I don't have that folder.
I actually want to compile this program https://github.com/KDE/kajongg

Comment: in readme nowhere specified which version of twisted to use. It has many changes after v12 and v15 so firstly i think you need to find exact version required to be install because many functionalities are added/removed in major versions. I am using twisted 12.0 for my project but thankfully it's on linux.
however you can try creating virtualenv in python to work on your project